# How to send bulk emails using PHP(Codeigniter)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, swiftmailer

Kindly tell me the way of sending multiple emails using php Codeigniter.

Comment: try to use Codeigniter-jobQueue https://github.com/marsanla/Codeigniter-jobQueue

Comment: if you send too many emails from 1 place those emails will mostlikely end up in spam filters so its better to use a service that is specialized in sending bulk mails.... like mailchimp for example or any other service out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use your own server for bulk email, if you are using a vps, the provider may have a spam filter and you will end up with  email pnalities, if not the vps host, then the client may flag your emails as a spam read more about [ANTI SPAM here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques)

**Solution**

use a third party email service api instead for example mailshimp , you can do alot with the free acount , they give you a free key and you're good to use their api
https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/example-code/

example:
let's say your api keys is kisaragi2015

```
$key = "kisaragi2015"
```

and you have a preprepared campaign on mailshimp with an id = 123

```
$cid = 123
```

you simply send it like so

```
send($key, $cid) ;
```

that's it, please see the doc for more details

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/

there are [other email service](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=mailshimp%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=2uuvVdLxFMmssAGRyafgAw#q=mail%20campaign%20service%20) but that's up to you to choose which one fits your needs the best

hope that helps !

Answer (score 1):

```
public function send_spam($to_address){
    $this->load->library('email');
    $message = 'some stuff, some files, some whatever';
    $this->email->clear();
    $this->email->from('spam@spam.com);
    $this->email->reply_to('noreply@spam.com);
    $this->email->to($to_address);
    $this->email->subject('DAT SPAM YO');
    $this->email->message($message);
    if($this->email->send()===TRUE){
        return true
    }
    return false;
 }

$emails = array('victim1@victim.com', 'victim2@victim.com');

foreach($emails as $victim){
    $this->send_spam($victim)
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. After I sent 15 emails to different email account, It gives an error."Your SMTP might not configure" but it start working perfectly another day.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your multiple emails as an array like this:

```
$more_email = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com');
$this->email->to($more_email);
$this->email->send()
```